# Using async library to assemble all tags from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, collections, sails.js

I am using sails.js to create a tag system that has many-to-many relations with an entity called `Post`. The way I am doing the association is to use a database table to correlate each `tagId` with the `postId`. Each Post can have multiple tags.

After I retrieve an array of `{tagId : 'tagId, postId: 'postId'}` objects, I need to retrieve the tag names for each `tagId`. I am using the `async` library, but the array of tag names (String) returns an empty one, from the logging info, I can see that the return happens before the completion of the iterator function. My code is following:

```
var tagIdPostIds = [
{tagId : 'abcx', postId: 1},
{tagId : 'abce', postId: 1},
{tagId : 'abcd', postId: 1},
];

if (tagIdPostIds) {
        var tagsArr = []; //container of tag names

        var findTagById = function(tagIdPostIdObj, cb) {
          var tagId = tagIdPostIdObj.tagId;

          Tag.findOneById(tagId, function (err, foundTag) {
            if (err) return sendErrorMsgCode(res, "error in retrieving a tag", 401);

            if (foundTag) {
              sails.log.info('pushing in tag: ' + foundTag.tagName);
              tagsArr.push(foundTag.tagName);
            }
          });

          cb(); //without this, the program just hangs, but why??

        }; //findTagById


        var retTagNames = function(err) {
          if (err) return sendErrorMsgCode(res, "error in assembling tag names", 401);
          sails.log.info('returning tagsArr: ' + JSON.stringify(tagsArr));
          return res.json(tagsArr);
        }; //retTagNames

        async.eachSeries(tagIdPostIds, findTagById, retTagNames);
      }
```

After reading the documentation of `async`, I think `async.map()` may be what I need to assemble all tags for a given `postId`. Or my way of using `async.eachSeries()` is wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: cb() needs to be called inside Tag.findOneById() after if (foundTag) {...}

Comment: well, that magically solved the problem. What's the secret for calling cb() after the if(foundTag){} block? thanks so much

Comment: because Tag.findOneById() is asynchronous so when cb() was outside, it signaled eachSeries() to continue the loop and gets to retTagNames() instead of waiting for all the iterations to finish before getting to retTagName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post this correct answer by incorporating @Ben's answer in his comments from above so others can easily find what worked for me:

```
var tagIdPostIds = [
{tagId : 'abcx', postId: 1},
{tagId : 'abce', postId: 1},
{tagId : 'abcd', postId: 1},
];

if (tagIdPostIds) {
        var tagsArr = []; //container of tag names

        var findTagById = function(tagIdPostIdObj, cb) {
          var tagId = tagIdPostIdObj.tagId;

          Tag.findOneById(tagId, function (err, foundTag) {
            if (err) return sendErrorMsgCode(res, "error in retrieving a tag", 401);

            if (foundTag) {
              sails.log.info('pushing in tag: ' + foundTag.tagName);
              tagsArr.push(foundTag.tagName);
            }
            cb(); //this must be placed inside an async call to make it work!
          });



        }; //findTagById


        var retTagNames = function(err) {
          if (err) return sendErrorMsgCode(res, "error in assembling tag names", 401);
          sails.log.info('returning tagsArr: ' + JSON.stringify(tagsArr));
          return res.json(tagsArr);
        }; //retTagNames

        async.eachSeries(tagIdPostIds, findTagById, retTagNames);
      }
```